# How can I terminate a Stream if I don't need any value from termination?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a Stream that does all processing in `peek()` methods. I don't need any result from the Stream, but I need a terminal operation in order for processing to occur. Of course I can terminate the Stream with `count()` (or any other operation), but that would be misleading as if I needed some result from Stream termination. What is the correct method to terminate the Stream in such case?

Here is the code for reference:

```
Stream<Collection<NetworkPart>> graphHolders = cutSegment.stream()
    .map(this::obtainCollectionFor);
for (NetworkPart part : edgesToNetworkParts.get(originalSegment)) {
    part.integrate(cutSegment);
    graphHolders = graphHolders.peek(gh -> gh.add(part));
}
graphHolders.count(); // Just to terminate
```

Comment: Why not put all the `part`s in a List and then do `graphHolders.forEach(gh -> gh.addAll(theParts))`? It seems you only have a need for this because of your use of `peek`.

Comment: @Radiodef, thank you very much, that was the problem indeed. I updated my own answer with the correct `peek()`-less code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I've rewritten the code from the question:

```
Collection<NetworkPart> partsOwningEdge = edgesToNetworkParts.get(originalSegment);
partsOwningEdge.forEach(part -> part.integrate(cutSegment));
cutSegment.stream()
    .map(this::obtainCollectionFor)
    .forEach(gh -> gh.addAll(partsOwningEdge));
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's just the 'misleading' that's irking you, try this:

```
private static void terminateStream(Stream<?> stream) { 
    stream.forEach(e -> {});
}
```

I think this would remove any ambiguity: The method has a clear purpose and the call is clear as well. When used as follows,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream<String> stream = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c").stream();
    stream = stream.peek(str -> System.out.println(str));
    terminateStream(stream);
}
```

The main method will print

```
a
b
c
```

This does require that `stream` is not closed and has not been operated upon, or it will throw an `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: This of course does the job, but that would be writing another method, and methods are supposed to be in the scope where they can be useful. This method can be useful anywhere, so I'd expect to find it in the standard library. There is `Function.identity()` for a similar case with mapping; is there a standard `Consumer` that does nothing?

Comment: @Suseika I haven't found any default implementations of `Consumer` in the standard library. You could always just place it as far up in your project hierarchy as possible.

Comment: Yup, I guess that is the best one can do.

Answer (score 2):

You could use allMatch() as a terminal operation as this does not need to be evaluated on all elements.

Comment: This would be the same as using `count()`. I don't need the boolean value returned by `allMatch()`

Comment: No, because count() needs to visit every element in the stream, while allMatch() only needs to visit one, non-matching element.

Comment: So it would be a construction like `streamToTerminate.allMatch(a->false);`, which is even uglier. The purpose of the question is to find out the solution that is the best at showing programmer's intent to terminate the stream without returning any value. `.allMathc(a->false)` is even worse than `count()` with such requirements for a terminal operation.